# module resolving is not working on babel-node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

So in my webpack i resolve app folder(inside my app folder are the "container" and "component" folder)

```
 resolve:{
    modules:[
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'app'),
     path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules'),
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
```

Then I'm using babel node for testing..  Here's server.js

```
 import path from 'path'
 import { Server } from 'http'
 import Express from 'express'
 import React from 'react'
 import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
 import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
 import Routes from 'containers/App/Routes'
```

The error is that node can't find  'containers/App/Routes'  but if I change  server.js like below, it works.

```
import Routes from './containers/App/Routes'
```

Do I need to add some configuration so that node  also read my  webpack resolve modules??  It's working fine in  webpack devserver

Comment: importing without relative path will search in the `node_modules` folder by default. have you tried to create an alias in `webpack` for `containers/App/Routes`?

Comment: For server side code what you need is https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-alias